# Django: select_related to a table vs table's field

Tags: django, django-models, django-select-related

I have 2 models

```
class A(models.Model):
    val = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    val2 = models.IntegerField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    val3 = models.IntegerField()
```

How is the query -

```
C.objects.select_related('B').all()
```

better than -

```
C.objects.select_related('B__val2').all()
```

And if not how query one can be optimised?

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter model you need, by lowcase filter of the child models

```
B.objects.filter(c__isnull=False)
```

read more here [lookups-that-span-relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Filtering is another way to do it. But if referencing the model's field could be used for that in some way than that would be better.